# 403 Error when accessing a new ASP.NET Core website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a new virtual server. I added a new user and gave it admin rights (identical to administrator). Then I disabled the administrator user, to avoid a common name that a hacker might try.

I have a deployment process that I used successfully multiple times when using administrator login. I am now trying to make work with a different login.

I logged in, and setup my web server using the new user credentials.  I published my site using FTP successfully. When I try and access the new site, I get a 403 Error (invalid credentials). The AppPool is set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`, but I cannot locate where that "user" is given privileges. I am assuming it doesn't have access to the inetpub directory where the web site resides.

The Microsoft articles on this don't match my 2023 server screens.  How do I give the `ApplicationPoolIdentity` access to the site?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code If an account has no permission, 401.3 is returned. 403 doesn't mean that, and you need to dig into IIS log files and learn the actual substatus code first.

Comment: 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Comment: Either it changes or I made a mistake.  Getting 401 error.

Comment: 2024-02-13 16:52:18 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET / - 443 - 10.4.124.143 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/121.0.0.0+Safari/537.36+Edg/121.0.0.0 - 401 3 5 103

Comment: You probably made quite a few changes to land on this 401.3 instead of 403. Unless you recorded all your changes and now roll them all back, you are asking for something unrealistic and no one here has the luxury of time. Please hire an experienced consultant instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the `401.3` error, you can try to this solution:

1. Navigate to the root of your web application : e.g. `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\[Website folder name]`
2. Right click on the file and go to "Properties > Security"
3. Click "Edit" and then click "Add"
4. Click "Advanced" in the bottom left
5. Click "Find Now" - this should list all the accounts available
6. Scroll till you find "IUSR" and select it
7. Click "OK" and click "OK" again
8. In the block "Permissions for IUSR" click on "allow" next to "Full Control"
9. Click apply (wait for the dialog to close)
10. Click "OK" and click "OK" again